# Filtering select options being passed from controller with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Good evening people. I have this question for knockout.js. I'm working with a table filtering form, it have 2 dropdowns, one parent and one child. The table is filtered by one of the dropdown or by the both of them. But, if I change the first dropdown, the second is filtered via an ajax call. The problem is, that the two dropdowns should be populated when the page is loaded on the html. Resuming. What I'm trying to do is to filter or removing the existing options from a populated dropdown and filling with the filtered options.

The code so far:

The HTML (its a Blade template, its rendering the html fine, Edited: the values are not the real values, just to put some of it)

```
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">messages.form_elemento_dependencia:</label>
            <select name="f_dependencia" data-bind="value: dependencia" id="f_dependencia" class="span12 campos_busqueda_bienes">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
            </select>
         </div>
     </div>

<div class="span3">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">messages.form_elemento_coordinacion:</label>
        <select id="options:coordinacionData, optionsText: "description",optionsCaption: "Seleccione", optionsValue: "id", value: coordinacion" class="span12 campos_busqueda_bienes" name="f_coordinacion">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

The JS (I know thats something is missing with the coordinationData array that's what I haven't found yet)

```
var ViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            self.dependencia = ko.observable();
            self.coordinacion = ko.observable();
            self.descripcion = ko.observable();
            self.dt = _sitiosDt;

            self.coordinacionData = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.bienes_t = ko.observableArray([]);

            self._filtra_dt = function(){
                _sitiosDt.fnDraw();
            };

            self.filtra_dt_click = function(data, event){
                self._filtra_dt();
            };

            self.filtra_dt = function(data, event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    self._filtra_dt();
                }
                return true;
            };

            self.limpia_campo_busqueda = function(){
                self.dependencia('');
                self.descripcion('');
            };

            self.dependencia.subscribe(function(newDependencia) {
                if(newDependencia){
                    $.getJSON("/coordinacionesjson", {'d':newDependencia}, function(data) {
                        var mappedData = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Item(item.id, item.description) });
                        self.coordinacionData(mappedData);
                    });
                    self.coordinacion('');
                }
            });



        };
        my = {viewModel : new ViewModel(_sitiosDt)};
        ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us the rendered output of the blade template - assuming it's done on the server side?

Comment: Done. It's a php template, used on Laravel. Thanks

Comment: You're HTML is invalid. Look at the quotes on the second `select` binding.

Comment: Well, it didn't in matter of fact. The array overrides the existing options and the second dropdown is empty. If I remove the options bind it doesn't filter the second dropdown